# Side effects of overnight Oats , Overnight fenugreek

Tags: food-safety, nutrient-composition, oats

i started to eat overnight oats . But i want to know what are the side effects of it .

Because i am not cooking or heating the oats . So i am really worrying if any kind of bacteria will enter to our body .

I just mix oats and milk and honey in a glass box and put it in refrigerator in the night , and in the morning i take it out and eat .

So what about the bacteria, what about cold food . And even how can we trust the quality of oats that come in packed may be some dusts in oats .

> I am planing to eat fenugreek , that i put it on water yesterday . The
>   purpose for this is hair growth . Is this good for health ? . Is there
>   any side effects ? I hear that fenugreek will reduce the spam count of
>   man

Comment: Sorry, we do not take questions on health. The part about the safety of eating food that has spent a night in the refrigerator is handled in the more general question I linked as a duplicate.

Comment: you see only refrigerator part and so you make it duplicate . Why you did this ? . There are so many other things in question . This is not a good method. Please help to get some answers

Comment: All other parts are off topic for our site. See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, the second point of the list for types of questions we don't take.

Comment: let me know theses questions are off topic or not https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19293/barley-vs-oats?rq=1 , https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3909/difference-between-old-fashioned-and-quick-oats?rq=1 and why you are not telling to them these are off topic

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/93425/can-i-heat-up-overnight-oats?rq=1

Comment: The questions you linked are not off topic. The link I gave you explains which questions are off topic, and which ones are acceptable. It is part of our help center, if you want, from there you can go to further pages of the help center.